# Spring Boot mvc path match strategy

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How actually works next property in Spring Boot if we declare it explicitly?

```
spring:
  mvc:
   pathmatch:
     matching-strategy: ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

Question related to this issue https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3462

Answer (score 3):

See the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web.servlet.spring-mvc.content-negotiation):

> As of Spring Framework 5.3, Spring MVC supports several implementation strategies for matching request paths to `Controller` handlers. It was previously only supporting the `AntPathMatcher` strategy, but it now also offers `PathPatternParser`. Spring Boot now provides a configuration property to choose and opt in the new strategy:

```yaml
spring:
  mvc:
    pathmatch:
      matching-strategy: "path-pattern-parser"
```

> For more details on why you should consider this new implementation, see the [dedicated blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2020/06/30/url-matching-with-pathpattern-in-spring-mvc).